# dottedtocline not work with MakeUppercase and hyperref on Overleaf

Tags: hyperref, overleaf, textcase

The following command works fine on my pc but doesn't work on Overleaf. The tableofcontents is strange and several errors appear. Any tips on how to resolve this?

```latex
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textcase}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{4em}{\bf \MakeUppercase{#1}}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please compile your `MWE` twice, it produced error in `PC` too

Comment: @MadyYuvi No error compiled with TeX Live 2023.

Comment: @hair-splitter Oh! sorry, I'm using MikTeX 2.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\MakeUppercase` try with `\uppercase`

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{4em}{\bf \protect\uppercase{#1}}{#2}}
\makeatother

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: that can work if your titles are simple but it is not a stable solution long term. So once overleaf updates better switch back to \MakeUppercase.